# How to get the size of a matrix?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Recently, I've got a project which needed to know the size of a matrix.
here is a section of matlab code.

```
[rwn1 rwn2]=size(rtt)
```

Then you will know how many rows and columns it have in the matrix called "rtt" from the code.But I want to transform the matlab code into python,I also have created a python code like this

```
import numpy as np
rtt=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
rtt.shape
```

it only printed (10,)
it didn't print the number of rows,just only the number of columns.
The result what i want is (10,1), does any master can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry,there is one thing i forgot to mention is that the matrix [1,2,3...] is hypothetical.The real situation is that the matrix is imported from excel.

Answer (score 0):

You are created an one dimension array.

```
import numpy as np  
rtt=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]) 
#rtt=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],ndmin=2) another way
rtt.shape #(1, 10)
```

If u want this in (column, row) format then

```
rtt.shape[::-1] #(10, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works,but the real array data is from excel.I think the method is only working on the hypothetical matrix which i created.

Comment: You could use openpyxl to extract data from excel

Comment: Thank you again! I've solved the question.And it also works very well when i import data from excel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences between numpy and matlab, that can be annoying for a new users. One of them is this; you need to do

```
    rtt = rtt.reshape(1,-1)
```

to get a row matrix. I think you'll find this documentation page helpful:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shape, but just make sure the row/column order is what you want:

```
>>> rtt = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> rtt
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> rtt.shape
(10,)
```

You say you want `(10,1)`:

```
>>> rtt.shape = (10,1)
>>> rtt
array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5],
       [ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 8],
       [ 9],
       [10]])
```

But maybe `(1,10)` is what you want:

```
>>> rtt.shape = (1,10)
>>> rtt
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

And if you want `(2,5)`, help yourself:

```
>>> rtt.shape = (2,5)
>>> rtt
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
>>>
```